# Updating an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of javascript objects like the following:

```
var food = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Apples', owned: true },
    {id: 2, name: 'Oranges', owned: false },
    {id: 3, name: 'Bananas', owned: true }
];
```

Then I receive another array with the following data:

```
var newFood = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Peas'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Oranges'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Bananas'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Grapefruits'}
];
```

How can I update the previous `food` array with the new information in `newFeed`, *without* overwriting the original `owned` property, while adding an `owned: false` to any new object?

Keep in mind this is plain javascript, not jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd probably want to index food by id so make food an object instead of an array:

```
var food = {
1: {name: "Apples", owned: true},
//...
}
```

then iterate over newFood and update the fields appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) for fix the problem.

```
var arrayObj = [
                {Name:'John',LastName:'Smith'},
                {Name:'Peter',LastName:'Jordan'},
                {Name:'Mike',LastName:'Tyson'}
              ];

var element = _.findWhere(arrayObj, { Name: 'Mike' });
element.Name="SuperMike";

console.log(arrayObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var temp = {};

for (var i = 0, l = food.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    temp[food[i].name] = true;
}

for (var i = 0, l = newFood.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    if ( !temp[newFood[i].name] ) {
        food.push( { id: food.length + 1, name: newFood[i].name, owned: false });
    }
}
```

The first `for` statement will populate the `temp` object with the fruit names from the `food` array, so that we know which fruits exist in it. In this case, `temp` will be this:

```
{ "Apples": true, "Oranges": true, "Bananas": true }
```

Then, the second `for` statement checks for each fruit in `newFood` if that fruit exists in `temp`, and if it doesn't, if pushes a new array item into the `food` array.

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this? [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/eC5AC/)

JavaScript

```
function updateFood( newFood, oldFood ) {
    var foodLength = oldFood.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < newFood.length; i++) {
        if (i > foodLength) { //add more if needed
            newFood[i].owned = false;
            oldFood.push(newFood[i]);
        } else if (!food[i].owned) { //replace if needed
            newFood[i].owned = false;
            oldFood[i] = newFood[i];
        }
    }
}
```